# Deixar imagem a imagem selecionada com opacidade maior que as demais de uma galeria

Tags: css

Tenho uma simples galeria, e quando seleciona uma imagem, essa mesma imagem e carregada via ajax em uma div que é posicionada ao lado dessa galeria.

Quando seleciono a imagem apenas o imagem muda, só que eu gostaria de melhorar a estetica. Tipo, tem a imagem A, B, C e D

Eu gostaria que quando eu selecionasse a imagem B, a opacidade dela ficasse em 1, e as outras imagens com uma opacidade de 0,7 (isso é só um exemplo), e caso eu selecionasse a imagem C ela ficasse com a opacidade 1 e a B ficaria 0,7

Comment: Quando você diz "selecionar", seria passando o mouse em cima? Clicando? Usando um checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe para a galeria de imagens e deixar por padrão todas as imagens com uma opacidade de não selecionada. Quando o usuário seleciona uma imagem, você adiciona uma classe CSS que indica que aquela imagem está selecionada e aumenta a sua opacidade.

```
.galeria img{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.galeria img.selecionada{
    opacity: 1;
}
```